# How to get the PackageName in a listview of an Android App using PackageManager

Tags: java, android, android-package-managers

The app I am developing requires that I get the package name using PackageManager.

[image]

I am able to get the App Icon and and App Name but how do I get the packagename in a way similar to what I have below?

```
    Drawable appIcon = packageManager
            .getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.applicationInfo);


    String appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(
            packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();
```

Comment: which package name do you mean here, is it in your list view?

Comment: like for example the code I have above is able to retrieve the app icons and app names of installed applications I have in a listview. How would I do that but for packagename preferably in the same manner?

Comment: what is the expected `packagename` of, for example, Flashlignt?

Comment: I am not sure but it would be in the format of com.blah.blah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it was

```
    PACKAGE_NAME = packageInfo.packageName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private ArrayList results = new ArrayList();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {
        results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName);
        Log.w("Installed Applications", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo
                .loadLabel(pm).toString());
    }
```

This gives list of all package names installed in your device.

```
rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm)
                .toString();
```

This gives u the app names.

```
rInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
```

And this gives the appicon.

Comment: Is `results` intentionally non-generic?

Answer (score 0):

```
String package_name= getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).packageName;
```

***Or***

```
String package_name= MyContext.getPackageName();
```